# How can I add the (virtual) ServerName value as customer Header in Apache2?

Tags: virtualhost, apache2, http-headers

I would like to get the ServerName on the HTTP response of Apache in a custom header.

Something like this:

Header Set X-VirtualServerName "%{SERVERNAME}"

Please consider this string can be different from the "host" declared in the request by the client due to ServerAlias directive and the ServerName may change between virtualhosts.